# Django through apache

Tags: django, apache

I am having a great deal of trouble deploying a django website written for 1.3 behind apache using django 1.4 and wsgi. There is also a wordpress site running on the same domain too. Ideally I would like to have django site running on [domain]/app/.

Does anybody have any links to a good tutorial. I am having a lot of trouble working out where to put wsgi.py file. It keeps saying it cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was recently working to deploy my first django project, I found [this tutorial](http://blog.stannard.net.au/2010/12/11/installing-django-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-10-04/) helpful. It independently tests if django and wsgi are working using simple "hello world" applications for each and gives an example of how to make the wsgi.py file work right. I think it's not really a question of putting wsgi.py in the right place; it's more a question of telling Apache where wsgi.py is. If you can get the tutorial working it ought to be relatively straightforward to get your full django site working.

Answer (score 0):

For the Django site, should simply be a matter of having:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app /some/path/project/wsgi.py
```

In other words, the '/app' mount point is used with WSGIScriptAlias instead of '/' that many examples use.

If using login features, you may also need to set LOGIN_URL etc in Django settings file however, as it doesn't automatically incorporate in the mount point.